# Create common method for (any) object initialization

Tags: c#, class, object

I've class with the name `A` and inside class `A` have many another user defined object properties (`B`,`C` etc.). For using class `A` i need create instance as

```
new A{ B = new B(), C = new C() ...}
```

This  scenario happens many times in my project and it makes my code a bit of untidy.

Now I need some code (or existing library, framework) for creating instance of this kind of classes using less code.

Comment: It is not clear at all what you are asking or what you are expecting as an answer. For any specific problem you are having **please include a [mcve]**. Please also read [How do I ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Use the constructor of your class

Comment: What do you mean with `less code`? This question is too generic. Can you providing a **[mcve]** ?

Comment: It's hard to answer such a vague question. I can think of two solutions: expand on the default constructor of A, so that the default values are created in the background for all the child objects, or write a helper class to instantiate your A objects.

Comment: Do you need to initialize the nested classes with specific variables? That's is why you can overload constructors to make object initialization easier :)

Comment: Use constructor for this purpose

Comment: Let me explain, i need something common piece of code to create any  class instance.  In my question class A is only sample class.  I hope i explained everything clearly :)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, lets use `Reflection`, I have created a `BaseClass`, and it looks like,

```
public class Base {

            public Base() {
                Type type = this.GetType(); // gets current type
                var props = type.GetProperties(); // get current type's properties

                foreach (var item in props) // B and C
                {
                    object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(item.PropertyType); // create instace of both B and C
                    item.SetValue(this, instance); // set B property to new value which we have created instance 

                }


            }
        }
```

And our container class which is A should be derived from `BaseClass` and should use Base's constructor, like this,

```
public class A : Base 
        {
            public A()  : base() { 

            }
            public B _B { get; set; }
            public C _C {get;set;}
        }
```

After implemeted this, just create instace from `A` and check the properties,

Hope helps,

Comment: i need common  method to create any class instance. In my question class A is only sample class.

Comment: See edit @Murad

Comment: This is a good approach, but  i want to call object initializer when i need not every time creating new object.

Comment: Use boolean parameter, pass true if you want, pass false if you don't want.. Or don't add `: base() ` if you don't want to use. In my opinion, this will reduce the code.. It is up to you anyway.

Comment: I need separated class(method) and if i use  public Base(){} constructor as method in a separated way  it will not work when object A has property B and object B has property C object.

Comment: You can make it recursive, if foreach item has more properties do the same.. @Murad

Comment: Yeah, thanks please correct your answer as well

Answer (score 0):

That is what (constructor, method) Overloading is there for :) See below example:

```
public class ClassA {

    public ClassA() {
        // Do some generic initialization here
        this.ClassB = new ClassB();
        this.ClassC = new ClassC();
    }

    // Always call the base constructor using : this()
    public ClassA(string name, int age) : this() {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Age = age;
    }

    // chain to another, 'simpler' constructor by doing  : this(name, age)
    public ClassA(string name, int age, ClassB classB) : this(name, age) {
        this.ClassB = classB;
    }

    public ClassA(string name, int age, ClassB classV, ClassC classC) : this(name, age, classV) {
        this.ClassC = classC;
    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public ClassB ClassB { get; set; }
    public ClassC ClassC { get; set; }
}

public class ClassB {
    public string School { get; set; }
    public string Class { get; set; }
}

public class ClassC {
    public string Area { get; set; }
    public string Suburb { get; set; }
}
```

and then call it like this:

```
public SomeMethod() {
    ClassA = new ClassA("John", 40, new ClassB(), new ClassC());
}
```

You can really make type initialization a lot easier by overloading constructors

Comment: i need common  method to create any class instance. In my question class A is only sample class.